# Problema al descomprimir en docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, shell

tengo el siguiente código en docker:

```
#With the next line will be installd the operative system
FROM ubuntu

#Is the actualization of repository
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install wget -y

#Install samtools
RUN wget https://github.com/samtools/samtools/releases/download/1.3.1/samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2 -o samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xjf samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2
RUN cd samtools-1.3.1.tar
RUN make
```

pero me aparece el siguiente error

```
Step 11/13 : RUN tar -xjf samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2
 ---> Running in 5f720d803ae2
bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file.
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
The command '/bin/sh -c tar -xjf samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

la verdad no se como solucionarlo. Ojala alguien pueda ayudarme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si el archivo es un Bzip2 valido, usa el comando bzip2 (`apt install bzip2 -y`) para chequearlo

```
bzip2 -d samtools-1.3.1.bz2
```

Como es un archivo .tar.bz2 agrega la opcion `v` para obtener mas info del proceso y si hay algun problema

```
tar xfvj samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2
```

Si sigue dando un error, comprueba que el archivo este presente en la ruta donde se va a descomprimir. Para asegurarte, usa `WORKDIR /ruta/al/archivo` antes de `RUN tar xfvj samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2`

Comment: El problema es que al parecer si es uno válido y con `tar -xjf <archivo>` si se puede descomprimir un archivo con la extensión `.bzip2`. Que extraño.

Answer (score 2):

El error no es por el comando para descomprimir el archivo, el error es porque el archivo que intentas decomprimir está corrupto.

El origen del problema es el comando para descargar el archivo. Es con O mayúscula, con o minúscula es para escribir en un log. Aquí va el comando correcto:

`wget https://github.com/samtools/samtools/releases/download/1.3.1/samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2 -O samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2`

Aunque si no quieres renombrar el archivo, como es en el caso de tu ejemplo, no hace falta que pases ningún parámetro, y el comando podría quedar así:

`wget https://github.com/samtools/samtools/releases/download/1.3.1/samtools-1.3.1.tar.bz2`

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: @AbatwaelQuitol si la respuesta solucionó tu problema, ¡acéptala! Lee [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) para más info